# Describe all natural numbers $n$ for which $3^{n}-2^{n}$ is divisible by $5$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

I need to describe all natural numbers $n$ for which $3^{n}-2^{n}$ is divisible by $5$.

After testing out some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, I came to the conclusion that $3^{n} - 2^{n}$ is divisible by $5$ iff $n$ is even - i.e., if $n$ is of the form $2k$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Here is my attempt so far:

$(\implies)$:

> To show that if $n$ is even, then $3^{n}-2^{n}$ is divisible by $5$, we prove that $\forall k \in N$, $3^{2k}-2^{2k} \equiv \,0 \mod 5$ by induction on $k$:
>
> - **Basis Step**: For $k = 1$, $3^{2(1)}-2^{2(1)}=3^{2}-2^{2}=9-4=5 \equiv\, 0 \mod 5 $.
> - **Suppose true for $\mathbf{k=m}$**: $3^{2m}-2^{2m}\equiv \, 0 \mod 5 \, \implies \, 3^{2m}-2^{2m}=5l$, $l \in \mathbb{Z}$.
> - **Show true for $\mathbf{k = m+1}$**: Consider $3^{2(m+1)}-2^{2(m+1)}\\ = 3^{2m+2}-2^{2m+2}\\ = 3^{2m}\cdot 3^{2}- 2^{2m}\cdot 2^{2}\\ = 9\cdot 3^{2m}-4 \cdot 2^{2m} \\= 5 \cdot 3^{2m} + 4\cdot 3^{2m} - 4 \cdot 2^{2m} \\ = 5(3^{2m}) + 4(3^{2m}-2^{2m}) \\ = 5(3^{2m})+4(5l)\, \text{(by the induction hypothesis)} \\ = 5(3^{2m} + 4l) \, \text{which is divisible by}\, 5.$
>
> So, by induction, then the statement $3^{2k}-2^{2k} \equiv \, 0 \mod 5$ holds $\forall k \geq 1 \, \implies \, $ the statement $3^{n}-2^{n} \equiv \, 0 \mod 5$ holds $\forall n = 2k$, $k \geq 1$.

$(\Longleftarrow)$:

> To show that $3^{n}-2^{n}$ divisible by $5$ $\implies$ $n$ even, we will show that $n$ odd $\implies$ $3^{n}-2^{n}$ is not divisible by $5$. Now, suppose the proposition is false. I.e., assume $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ for which $n$ is odd, but $3^{n}-2^{n}$ is divisible by $5$.
>
> Since $n$ is odd, it is of the form $2k+1$, $k \in \mathbb{N}$.
>
> So, we have that $3^{2k+1}-2^{2k+1} \equiv \, 0 \mod 5 \, \implies \, 3^{2k+1} - 2^{2k+1} = 5l$, $l \in \mathbb{N}$.
>
> So, $\displaystyle \frac{3^{2k+1}}{5} - \frac{2^{2k+1}}{5} = l$.

At this point, I got stuck. I think my $(\implies)$ direction is fine, but I definitely need help on my $(\Longleftarrow)$ direction.

Could somebody please help me complete this proof?

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: $3^{2k+1}-2^{2k+1} = 3^{2k} + 2(3^{2k} - 2^{2k})$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$3^{2k+1}-2^{2k+1}= 3(9^k)-2(4^k) \equiv 3(-1)^k-2(-1)^k=(-1)^k  \mod 5$$

$$3^{2k}-2^{2k}= (9^k)-(4^k) \equiv (-1)^k-(-1)^k=0  \mod 5$$

Answer (score 4):

I think this is a little easier to see using modular arithmetic. Note that $5$ divides $3^n - 2^n$ means $3^n \equiv 2^n \pmod{5}$.  Since $3 \cdot 2 = 6 \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$, then $3 = 2^{-1}$ in $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$.  Then
\begin{align*}
2^n \equiv 3^n \equiv (2^{-1})^n = 2^{-n} \pmod{5}
\end{align*}
and multiplying through by $2^n$ yields $2^{2n} \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$.  This means that the order of $2$ in the unit group $(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})^\times$ divides $2n$.  Since $2$ has order $4$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})^\times$, then $4$ divides $2n$, so $2$ divides $n$, i.e., $n$ is even.  All the implications above are actually two-sided (iff), so we find that $5$ divides $3^n - 2^n$ iff $n$ is even.

Comment: is there a way to state the last part without referring to the concept of groups?

Comment: and $2$ has order $5$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{5}$

Comment: @JessyCat $2$ has order $4$ in the group of units under multiplication since $2^4 = 16 \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$ and $4$ is the smallest such positive integer.  You can certainly rephrase the last part without groups, but you will basically have to reprove a special case of [Lagrange's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)) to conclude that $4$ divides $2n$.

Comment: at this point, we have not even defined what a group is. I'm also not sure I understand why the group of units under multiplication is relevant...

Comment: @JessyCat The group of units is relevant because I used it in my proof! :)  More seriously, I used the structure of the group of units because I was trying to solve the equation $2^{2n} = 1$ in $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$. $1$ is the identity of the group of units, so it seemed very natural to me.  You clearly know a little group theory (since you told me the order of $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ under addition), so why not try to use it to solve the problem?

Comment: If you don't know Lagrange's Theorem, maybe you won't understand all of my answer right now (although I did include a link to the Wikipedia page describing the result).  But maybe you will find the answer more useful once you've seen some more group theory.  In any case, I usually find proofs by induction unenlightening, and I think my proof is more elegant.  But you are of course free to disagree! :)  Anyway, if you would like me to clarify a part of my answer, I'm happy to elaborate.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:** $$3^{2k+1} - 2^{2k+1} = 3\cdot 3^{2k} - 2 \cdot 2^{2k} = 3(3^{2k} - 2^{2k}) + 2^{2k}$$

Now can you see why the first summand is divisible by 5 and the second isn't?

Comment: am I allowed to allude to the $(\implies)$ direction to say that $3(3^{2k}-2^{2k})$ is divisible by $5$?

Comment: @JessyCat Of course yes if it's been proven, which has been.